# How to properly connect to AWS LUN storage?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, iscsi

Recently I configured my LUN storage on the AWS, allowed TCP and UDP connections from my PC, made a port (3260 for iSCSI) forward rule to my local VM, allowed iSCSI firewall rules on both machines but I'm still missing something since I fail to discover my AWS iSCSI target, can someone tell me what am I missing?

AWS machine is running Windows Server 2016 while my local VM is running Windows Server 2019.

P.S. - I know iSCSI over WAN is a terrible idea but I need to do a quick test (for my college) to prove that it will be a disaster to use iSCSI over WAN for both security and performance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your AWS security group for the instance to make sure the right ports are open to your public IP.

Comment: It might be easier and more secure to setup VPN connection benween AWS machin and local Windows VM. Are you adding the IP of your AWS machine on the Discovery tab of your local machine?